# Giving one of two options

Tags: excel, calculated-column-formula, formula

I am really new to all of this, but I'm trying to edit a column with the following:

```
=OR(LEFT([Ticket Number],6)
="TASK00",LEN([Ticket Number])=0)
```

where the user is required to enter their ticket number as "TASK00XXXXX" where X is the number of the ticket. I would like to adjust this to limit them to both TASK00 and RITM00 but I'm not having much luck. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=OR( LEFT([Ticket Number],6)="TASK00",
     LEFT([Ticket Number],6)="RITM00",
     LEN([Ticket Number])=0 )
```

Comment: Yes - that's perfect! Being new, I think the way in which the formula I was working with was formatted is what screwed me up. Your spacing and indentation made it pretty clear how it works together. Thank you!